# Symbol present in DLL but launch returns "The procedure entry point could not be located in the DLL"

Tags: visual-studio, dll, dllimport

I am linking with third-party DLL and get

```
The procedure entry point jtagatlantic_write could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\My\Code\Tests\CppConsoleTest\x64\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe.
```

when application begins to load. I verified the linker command includes jtag_atlantic.lib and from dumpbin it looks like the reported symbol is present.

The lib file was generated from the following jtag_atlantic.def

```
EXPORTS
jtagatlantic_bytes_available
jtagatlantic_cable_warning
jtagatlantic_close
jtagatlantic_flush
jtagatlantic_get_error
jtagatlantic_get_info
jtagatlantic_is_setup_done
jtagatlantic_open
jtagatlantic_open
jtagatlantic_read
jtagatlantic_scan_thread
jtagatlantic_wait_open
jtagatlantic_write
```

by

```
lib /def:jtag_atlantic.def /machine:x64 /out:jtag_atlantic.lib
```

What else should I check?

```
  Dump of file jtag_atlantic.dll

  File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for jtag_atlantic.dll

  00000000 characteristics
  5B999615 time date stamp Thu Sep 13 01:41:25 2018
        0.00 version
        1 ordinal base
        19 number of functions
        19 number of names

  ordinal hint RVA      name

        1    0 00001420 ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1close@@YAXPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@J@Z = ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1close@@YAXPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@J@Z (void __cdecl Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1close(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *,long))
        2    1 00001450 ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1flush@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@J@Z = ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1flush@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@J@Z (long __cdecl Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1flush(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *,long))
        3    2 000014B0 ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1get_1last_1open_1error@@YAPEAV_jstring@@PEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@@Z = ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1get_1last_1open_1error@@YAPEAV_jstring@@PEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@@Z (class _jstring * __cdecl Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1get_1last_1open_1error(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *))
        4    3 000014C0 ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1open@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@PEAV_jstring@@JJ@Z = ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1open@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@PEAV_jstring@@JJ@Z (long __cdecl Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1open(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *,class _jstring *,long,long))
        5    4 00001540 ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1read@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@JPEAV_jbyteArray@@@Z = ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1read@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@JPEAV_jbyteArray@@@Z (long __cdecl Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1read(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *,long,class _jbyteArray *))
        6    5 000015D0 ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1write@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@JPEAV_jbyteArray@@@Z = ?Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1write@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jobject@@JPEAV_jbyteArray@@@Z (long __cdecl Java_com_altera_jnijtagatlantic_JtagAtlanticConnection_n_1write(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *,long,class _jbyteArray *))
        7    6 00001C90 ?jtagatlantic_bytes_available@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_bytes_available@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (int __cdecl jtagatlantic_bytes_available(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        8    7 00001CB0 ?jtagatlantic_cable_warning@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_cable_warning@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (int __cdecl jtagatlantic_cable_warning(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        9    8 00001CC0 ?jtagatlantic_close@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_close@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (void __cdecl jtagatlantic_close(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        10    9 00001CE0 ?jtagatlantic_flush@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_flush@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (int __cdecl jtagatlantic_flush(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        11    A 00001D40 ?jtagatlantic_get_error@@YA?AW4JATL_ERROR@@PEAPEBD@Z = ?jtagatlantic_get_error@@YA?AW4JATL_ERROR@@PEAPEBD@Z (enum JATL_ERROR __cdecl jtagatlantic_get_error(char const * *))
        12    B 00001D60 ?jtagatlantic_get_info@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEAPEBDPEAH2@Z = ?jtagatlantic_get_info@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEAPEBDPEAH2@Z (void __cdecl jtagatlantic_get_info(struct JTAGATLANTIC *,char const * *,int *,int *))
        13    C 00001D90 ?jtagatlantic_is_setup_done@@YA_NPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_is_setup_done@@YA_NPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (bool __cdecl jtagatlantic_is_setup_done(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        14    D 00001DA0 ?jtagatlantic_open@@YAPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDHH0@Z = ?jtagatlantic_open@@YAPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDHH0@Z (struct JTAGATLANTIC * __cdecl jtagatlantic_open(char const *,int,int,char const *))
        15    E 00001DC0 ?jtagatlantic_open@@YAPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDHH0PEAVLOCK_HANDLER@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_open@@YAPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDHH0PEAVLOCK_HANDLER@@@Z (struct JTAGATLANTIC * __cdecl jtagatlantic_open(char const *,int,int,char const *,class LOCK_HANDLER *))
        16    F 00002150 ?jtagatlantic_read@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEADI@Z = ?jtagatlantic_read@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEADI@Z (int __cdecl jtagatlantic_read(struct JTAGATLANTIC *,char *,unsigned int))
        17   10 00002160 ?jtagatlantic_scan_thread@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_scan_thread@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (void __cdecl jtagatlantic_scan_thread(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        18   11 00002170 ?jtagatlantic_wait_open@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = ?jtagatlantic_wait_open@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z (int __cdecl jtagatlantic_wait_open(struct JTAGATLANTIC *))
        19   12 000021B0 ?jtagatlantic_write@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDI@Z = ?jtagatlantic_write@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDI@Z (int __cdecl jtagatlantic_write(struct JTAGATLANTIC *,char const *,unsigned int))

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        3000 .text


  Dump of file jtag_atlantic.dll

  PE signature found

  File Type: DLL

  FILE HEADER VALUES
              8664 machine (x64)
              5 number of sections
        5B999BA2 time date stamp Thu Sep 13 02:05:06 2018
              0 file pointer to symbol table
              0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
              2022 characteristics
                    Executable
                    Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                    DLL

  OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
              20B magic # (PE32+)
        12.00 linker version
              2C00 size of code
              2200 size of initialized data
              0 size of uninitialized data
              3460 entry point (0000000180003460) _DllMainCRTStartup
              1000 base of code
        180000000 image base (0000000180000000 to 0000000180008FFF)
              1000 section alignment
              200 file alignment
              6.00 operating system version
              0.00 image version
              6.00 subsystem version
              0 Win32 version
              9000 size of image
              400 size of headers
              0 checksum
              3 subsystem (Windows CUI)
              160 DLL characteristics
                    High Entropy Virtual Addresses
                    Dynamic base
                    NX compatible
        100000 size of stack reserve
              1000 size of stack commit
        100000 size of heap reserve
              1000 size of heap commit
              0 loader flags
              10 number of directories
              4900 [     646] RVA [size] of Export Directory
              4F48 [      50] RVA [size] of Import Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Resource Directory
              7000 [     2F4] RVA [size] of Exception Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Certificates Directory
              8000 [      2C] RVA [size] of Base Relocation Directory
              4210 [      38] RVA [size] of Debug Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Architecture Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Global Pointer Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
              4350 [      70] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Bound Import Directory
              4000 [     1D8] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Delay Import Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of COM Descriptor Directory
              0 [       0] RVA [size] of Reserved Directory


  SECTION HEADER #1
  .text name
  2AFB virtual size
  1000 virtual address (0000000180001000 to 0000000180003AFA)
  2C00 size of raw data
  400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 00002FFF)
        0 file pointer to relocation table
        0 file pointer to line numbers
        0 number of relocations
        0 number of line numbers
  60000020 flags
        Code
        Execute Read

  SECTION HEADER #2
  .rdata name
  1884 virtual size
  4000 virtual address (0000000180004000 to 0000000180005883)
  1A00 size of raw data
  3000 file pointer to raw data (00003000 to 000049FF)
        0 file pointer to relocation table
        0 file pointer to line numbers
        0 number of relocations
        0 number of line numbers
  40000040 flags
        Initialized Data
        Read Only

  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
  -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
  5B999BA2 cv            2A 000043C0     33C0    Format: RSDS, {89F3C38C-E494-4FF4-AB3B-90068B504087}, 1, jtag_atlantic.pdb
  5B999BA2 feat          14 000043EC     33EC    Counts: Pre-VC++ 11.00=0, C/C++=15, /GS=14, /sdl=0, guardN=0

  SECTION HEADER #3
  .data name
        C0 virtual size
  6000 virtual address (0000000180006000 to 00000001800060BF)
  200 size of raw data
  4A00 file pointer to raw data (00004A00 to 00004BFF)
        0 file pointer to relocation table
        0 file pointer to line numbers
        0 number of relocations
        0 number of line numbers
  C0000040 flags
        Initialized Data
        Read Write

  SECTION HEADER #4
  .pdata name
  2F4 virtual size
  7000 virtual address (0000000180007000 to 00000001800072F3)
  400 size of raw data
  4C00 file pointer to raw data (00004C00 to 00004FFF)
        0 file pointer to relocation table
        0 file pointer to line numbers
        0 number of relocations
        0 number of line numbers
  40000040 flags
        Initialized Data
        Read Only

  SECTION HEADER #5
  .reloc name
        2C virtual size
  8000 virtual address (0000000180008000 to 000000018000802B)
  200 size of raw data
  5000 file pointer to raw data (00005000 to 000051FF)
        0 file pointer to relocation table
        0 file pointer to line numbers
        0 number of relocations
        0 number of line numbers
  42000040 flags
        Initialized Data
        Discardable
        Read Only

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        3000 .text
```

Comment: The error message points to `ConsoleTest.exe`, while the dump is of `jtag_atlantic.dll`. Check that you're using the correct file in your code.

Comment: Anyway, show the relevant piece of code and tag the question accordingly so we can help.

Comment: Additional to the above, I can't see a function exported with that name. The exports all seem to have mangled names.

Comment: @Alejandro There is no relevant piece of code because the exe throws error even when all calls to DLL functions are commented out. What do you mean by "tag" - are current tags not relevant to the question?

Comment: @Alejandro Sorry, forgot to mention I generated lib from dll manually. See the edited question, please.

Comment: @jackhab What the `.def` declares as `EXPORTS` doesn't match what the `.dll` actually exports. The `.def` has `jtagatlantic_write` vs. `?jtagatlantic_write@@YAHPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@PEBDI@Z` in the `.dll`. So you link with a `.lib` that doesn't match what is found in the `.dll` at runtime, which causes the errors you see.

Comment: @dxiv I tried to add decorated names to the .def and make a new .lib and it does not work, same if I try to undecorate the names with `?jtagatlantic_close@@YAXPEAUJTAGATLANTIC@@@Z = jtagatlantic_close`.

Comment: @jackhab The error message references `the dynamic link library ... ConsoleTest.exe`, which is a different module than the `jtag_atlantic.dll` you show the exports for. Some code and step-by-step of what goes where would help at this point. Also, just curious, but why not use `__declspec(dllexport)` like it's usually done.

Comment: @dxiv I can't __declspec(dllexport) since I don't have neither the DLL code nor it's original LIB; I'm trying to use third-party DLL. More over it is possible that I could have different version of the DLL which have their symbols mangled differently. So I'm looking for a way to write the client app which uses unmangled names and somehow be able to access whichever DLL version is currently present.

Comment: @jackhab If you need to bind unknown symbols at runtime, then your choices are to `LoadLibrary` then `GetProcAddress`, or link to whatever `.lib` you have, declare the library as delay-load, and override the [helper function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/understanding-the-helper-function?view=msvc-160) to resolve the right target for each symbol. In either case, you need to know the mangled name(s) you look for, or otherwise list all exported names at runtime and use some heuristics to decide which one "matches".

Comment: @dxiv From the all the comments above I understand that implicit library loading what I have to do but is there even a way to programmatically list DLL symbols without using MSVS dev. tools? I couldn't find anything in MS docs...

Comment: @jackhab You could take some inspiration from [detours](https://github.com/microsoft/detours) or [dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies).

Comment: @dxiv dependencies looks very interesting and useful. Thanks.